# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspchart

I have a bar chart which has different series .Each series has to point different page.
I am giving URL.I got this error.

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection.   Parameter name: index     Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the execution of the current web   request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out
>   of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the
>   collection. Parameter name: index
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 133:series1.Points[i].MapAreaAttributes = "Target=\"_blank\""; 
>   Line 134:series1.Points[0].Url = "db_PMUKPI_ByRM.aspx?Month=" + 
>   iMonth + "&Year=" + iYear; Line 135:series1.Points[1].Url =
>   "db_PmuKpi_AllMonths.aspx?Month=" + iMonth + "&Year=" + iYear; Line
>   136:series1.Points[2].Url = "db_PmuKpi_AllMonths.aspx?Month=" + iMonth
>   + "&Year=" + iYear; Line 137:series1.Points[3].Url = "db_PmuKpi_Overall_DateRange.aspx?Month=" + iMonth + "&Year=" + iYear;

Comment: What's unclear about the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the actual code, I'm going to assume you are using some sort of a loop and line 133 is inside the loop. It appears you are trying to access your object series1.Points[i], i being the index. Remember indexes generally start at 0 and end at number of objects - 1. So if you are using a for..loop, do it this way:

```
int numItems = series1.Points.Count();
for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
{
series1.Points[i].MapAreaAttributes = "Target=\"_blank\"";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GridView missing Datakeyname="id"